# Columns child equal per row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a product gallery that needs to be equal in height for the parent and the child div.

I need to calculate it per row. But I'm getting the tallest child and it was applying on all the div. What I want is get the highest div and apply it by row.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var item_title_height = 0;
 var item_details_height = 0;

 $('.item-title').each(function(i, obj) {
    if($(this).height() > item_title_height) {
    item_title_height = $(this).height();
  }
 });

 $('.item-details').each(function(i, obj) {
    if($(this).height() > item_details_height) {
    item_details_height = $(this).height();
  }
 });

$(".item-title").height(item_title_height);
$(".item-details").height(item_details_height);

});
```

This is my fiddle

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qr48S/51/)

Hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you would do this in jQuery.  but you could easily find the largest div with vanilla.  Use window.getComputedStyle to get styling info for elements that may not have explicit css or html style declarations.

```
var heights = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('item-title')).map(function(i){
    var cs = window.getComputedStyle(i,null)
    return parseFloat(cs.getPropertyValue("height"))
});
alert(Math.max.apply(null,heights))
```

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I infer: You want to look at each row, find the highest div in that row, and set all the divs in that row to that height. Meaning not all rows will have equal height, but all columns within a row will have equal height.

To do that, you need to have a way to group these by row. I changed your html so that every 3 child divs are wrapped in a "row" div.

See the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qr48S/54/ (edit - fixed link)

```
$(document).ready(function() {


  $('.row').each(function(){
    var item_title_height = 0;
    var item_details_height = 0;
    $(this).find('.item-title').each(function(i, obj) {
        if($(this).height() > item_title_height) {
          item_title_height = $(this).height();
        }
    });

    $(this).find('.item-details').each(function(i, obj) {
        if($(this).height() > item_details_height) {
          item_details_height = $(this).height();
        }
    });

    $(this).find('.item-title').height(item_title_height);
    $(this).find('.item-details').height(item_details_height);
  });
});
```

You need to loop over each row and then loop over each div within that row and apply the change to all divs within that row. Hope that helps!

Comment: Actually this is a ecommerce site and I cannot make the columns inside multiple rows. It needs to be one row and the rest will be columns

Comment: Understood. I'll just say having some way of partitioning by row is going to help you out a lot and it shouldn't be too involved.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could relay on CSS and javascript for this

```js
// JS maybe not necessary
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item-container {
  width:350px;
  flex:1 1 auto;
  margin: 5px;
  border: solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: gray;
  padding:0!important;/* overides bootstrap */
}
.item-details {
  flex: 1;
  background: white;
}

.item-button {
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: right;
}
/* image width a bit responsive ? */

img {
  width:100%;
  max-width:500px;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item-container col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="image"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
      <div class="item-title"> title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title </div>
      <div class="item-details">
        <p>details 1</p>
        <p>details 2</p>
        <p>details 3</p>
        <p>details 4</p>

      </div>
      <div class="item-button"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add to cart</button> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="image"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
      <div class="item-title"> title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title </div>
      <div class="item-details">
        <p>details 1</p>
        <p>details 2</p>
        <p>details 3</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item-button">
        <buttn type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add to cart</button>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="item-container col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="image"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
      <div class="item-title"> title title title title </div>
      <div class="item-details">
        <p>details 1</p>
        <p>details 2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item-button"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add to cart</button> </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item-container col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="image"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
      <div class="item-title"> title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title </div>
      <div class="item-details">
        <p>details 1</p>
        <p>details 2</p>
        <p>details 3</p>
        <p>details 4</p>
        <p>details 5</p>
        <p>details 6</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item-button"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add to cart</button> </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item-container col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="image"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
      <div class="item-title"> title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title </div>
      <div class="item-details">
        <p>details 1</p>
        <p>details 2</p>
        <p>details 3</p>
        <p>details 4</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item-button">
        <buttn type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add to cart</button>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="item-container col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="image"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
      <div class="item-title"> title title title title </div>
      <div class="item-details">
        <p>details 1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item-button"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add to cart</button> </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item-container col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="image"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
      <div class="item-title"> title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title </div>
      <div class="item-details">
        <p>details 1</p>
        <p>details 2</p>
        <p>details 3</p>
        <p>details 4</p>

      </div>
      <div class="item-button"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add to cart</button> </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item-container col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="image"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
      <div class="item-title"> title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title </div>
      <div class="item-details">
        <p>details 1</p>
        <p>details 2</p>
        <p>details 3</p>
        <p>details 4</p>
        <p>details 5</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item-button">
        <buttn type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add to cart</button>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="item-container col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="image"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
      <div class="item-title"> title title title title </div>
      <div class="item-details">
        <p>details 1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item-button"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add to cart</button> </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item-container col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="image"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
      <div class="item-title"> title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title </div>
      <div class="item-details">
        <p>details 1</p>
        <p>details 2</p>
        <p>details 3</p>
        <p>details 4</p>

      </div>
      <div class="item-button"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add to cart</button> </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item-container col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="image"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
      <div class="item-title"> title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title </div>
      <div class="item-details">
        <p>details 1</p>
        <p>details 2</p>
        <p>details 3</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item-button">
        <buttn type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add to cart</button>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="item-container col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="image"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
      <div class="item-title"> title title title title </div>
      <div class="item-details">
        <p>details 1</p>
        <p>details 2</p>
        <p>details 3</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item-button"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add to cart</button> </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item-container col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="image"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
      <div class="item-title"> title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title </div>
      <div class="item-details">
        <p>details 1</p>
        <p>details 2</p>
        <p>details 3</p>
        <p>details 4</p>

      </div>
      <div class="item-button"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add to cart</button> </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item-container col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="image"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
      <div class="item-title"> title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title </div>
      <div class="item-details">
        <p>details 1</p>
        <p>details 2</p>
        <p>details 3</p>
        <p>details 4</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item-button">
        <buttn type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add to cart</button>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="item-container col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="image"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
      <div class="item-title"> title title title title </div>
      <div class="item-details">
        <p>details 1</p>
        <p>details 2</p>
        <p>details 3</p>
        <p>details 4</p>

      </div>
      <div class="item-button"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add to cart</button> </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

**[demo](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/full/yOEXKM/)**